# Question about joint distribution of Bernoulli random variables under constraint that sum must be 1

Tags: distributions, joint-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, constraint

I am stuck with a problem at work. Can anybody please help me to give me the joint distribution of $n$ Bernoulli random variables but under the constraint that the sum of the these $n$ random variables must be $1$.

Can anybody show me how to derive this distribution?

Answer (score 4):

This is a categorical distribution, also known as a multinomial distribution with number of trials equal to $1$.

If the binomial probabilities are $q_k, \;k=1,\dots n$ then the multinomial probability is
$$p_k=\frac {q_k\prod_{j\neq k} (1-q_j)}{\sum_r q_r\prod_{s\neq r}(1-q_s)}$$

To derive this you simply use the conditional probability $p (A_k|B)=p (A_kB)/p (B) $ where $A_k$ is the event "variable $k $ is equal to $1$" and $B $ is the event "sum of all $n $ variables equals 1".  Then you can deduce that for both $A_k $ and $B $ to be true, all the other bernoulli variables must be zero.  This probability is the numerator for the value of $p_k $ I gave earlier.  Then $p (B)=\sum_r p (A_rB)$ using law of total probability and independence and the denominator I gave.

Answer (score 3):

There are only $n$ ways the variables can sum to $1$: one of them will equal $1$ and the other $n-1$ will equal zero.  The very phrasing of the question indicates the variables are exchangeable: thus, the joint distribution will not change when the variables are permuted.  Since permutations of the variables merely change each of these outcomes into other outcomes, *they are all equally likely*.  Consequently **the distribution is the uniform one on those $n$ outcomes, with probability $1/n$ for each outcome.**  *That fully describes the joint distribution.*

---

#### Edit

The original question assumed neither exchangeability nor independence.  But without making some such assumption, the only conclusion we can draw is that the joint distribution is *some* distribution on the $n$ possible outcomes I have described.  The probabilities may be any $n$ non-negative values that sum to unity, as required by the axioms of probability.

Comment: The OP seems agnostic about exchangeability to me - it does not say the RVs are the same bernoulli distribution, just that there are $n $ of them.

Comment: @probability That's a good point: the OP did not explicitly assume exchangeability.  Then again, neither did they assume independence--but without independence nothing of any value can be said.